# Using PR Build as a Subdomain to Google Cloud Triggered Builds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

We are using Google Cloud triggered builds ([refer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#default_routing)) and are successfully able to see results like:

```
https://VERSION_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

We use API keys for Maps etc. and would like to restrict access to websites. For this, there's wild card allowed in API Credentials page ([refer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions)) for ex:

```
https://*.example.com
```

however, it doesn't allow:

```
https://*-some-random-string.example.com
```

We would like to overcome this issue so we can restrict the keys to our PR builds only, how do we do this?

One option would be to have PR builds like:

```
https://VERSION_ID.PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

so we could use `https://*.PROJECT_ID.appspot.com` in API Credential restrictions, but I can't figure how to create PR builds as sub domains.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

GCP does indeed allow patterns in URLs for Credentials:

```
*-some-random-string.example.com/*
```

The reason it wasn't working for us was something else, and not this capability.